# Can I change the autofill on try catch block in .net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ide

In visual studio when I type the word try it automatically adds the catch and and try for me.

I want to add after the catch something like Msgbox(ex.message)... I'm tired to type the same thing over and over.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you call "autofill" is called code snippets, and what you want to do is to edit the [code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx) for `try`.

However, as a built in snippet, this is not possible, but you can [create your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165393.aspx).

For example, create a snippet called mtry (for My try) that has the exact functionality you want.